# Firefox adds -moz- prefix to min-content , max-content . Then fails to render it properly

Tags: css, firefox, grid, css-grid, developer-tools

Is it just me, but while using Firefox Developer Edition 60.0b4 (64 bit) I'm experiencing strange behavior using developer tools. Adding no prefixes to the code Firefox is adding them in, itself. Then reading them as errored lines and thus not displaying correctly. (Chrome dev tools does not suffer this problem and shows grid layout as intended)

this is my code from VS Studio 2017

```
    z-index: 2;
    grid-template-rows: 43vh min-content min-content max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "SectionSpacer" "SectionHeading" "SectionGalleryList" "SectionText";
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

This is what firefox reads

```
z-index: 2;
-ms-grid-rows: 43vh -moz-min-content min-content -moz-max-content;
grid-template-rows: 43vh -moz-min-content min-content -moz-max-content;
grid-template-areas: "SectionSpacer" "SectionHeading" "SectionGalleryList" "SectionText";
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Am using Firefox Developer Edition 60.0b4 (64 bit)

[image]

Comment: Does the same issue exist in other versions of Firefox? And can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: `min-content` is still experimental and not fully supported by some browsers. Have you considered the `auto` value instead?

Comment: I have managed to refactor the page with converted CSS in a JSfiddle and it works fine. I was hoping to determine if there is anything in angular 5 , maybe the cli, which may be adding this prefix. Possibly bootstrap, possibly css version,

Comment: After having cleared the history and cache  and a restart this has gone away. Both Firefox Developer and Vanilla are working as expected. Sorry Cant tell what resolved this but just glad its gone.